# Apk fails CTS test: shouldNotFIndUnexpectedIntents, no idea why

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, cts

**History:**

A client of ours has integrated our SDK library for Android. They try to pass Google's compatibility test (CTS).

**The issue:**

They failed CTS test suit with the following message:
android.signature.cts.intent.intentTest#shouldNotFindUnexpectedIntents | Result fail | java.lang.AssertionError: [package <*their package*> Invalid Intent: [android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE]].

**The main question:**

***My goal is to help them pass this test but I'm not sure what the real problem is and how to solve it. Can anyone help?***

**Details:**

1) I cannot currently extract information from our client at all about their host apk. All I know is that they're testing a **priv-app apk** for **Android 8.0 devices**. (It's legitimately a priv-app and should be). I cannot be sure for the next few days but I believe their targetSdk is 26 (i.e., Android 8.0.0)

2) Our SDK library contains a Broadcast Receiver that's defined as following:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="<our Broadcast Receiver class path>">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <action android:name="com.dt.ignite.startService"/>
            <action android:name="<our package>.<our custom intent name 1>"/>
            <action android:name="<our package>.<our custom intent name 2>"/>
            <action android:name="<our package>.<our custom intent name 3>"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

3) Looking at the source code of this specific CTS test (IntentTest.java) I understand it's failing because the ApplicationInfo of this apk contains an Intent which is not a "platform Intent", specifically "BROADCAST_COMPLETE". (https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/274)

4) The above made me think of Google's newly introduced "Background Limitations" and how they ban implicit Intent receivers from Android 8.0 and on. However, it is stated that BROADCAST_COMPLETE would be exempt from this ban. (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [test in question](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/cts/tests/signature/src/android/signature/cts/IntentTest.java#lookupPlatformIntents) checks if any `Intent`s are referenced in the manifest that are NOT **Platform `Intent`s**. It does this by checking for all `Intent`s that start with `android.intent.action` that are not in the list of **Platform `Intent`s**.

To pass the test you will need to either remove `BOOT_COMPLETED` from the `<intent-filter>` or replace it with a suitable **Platform `Intent`**

See also this problem report: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/274